# Error running generator.dart to create Dart client library for App Engine API

Tags: google-app-engine, dart, endpoint

Am getting the following stack trace when running the following command:

```bash
dart generate.dart package -input googleapis-discovery-documents/ -output googleapis/
```

My downloaded App Engine API discovery doc is inside googleapis-discovery-documents/ in the current directory.

```
NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'toLowerCase'
Receiver: null
Arguments: []
    #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
    #1      ApisPackageGenerator.generateApiPackage (package:discoveryapis_generator/src/apis_package_generator.dart:70:49)
    #2      generateApiPackage (package:discoveryapis_generator/discoveryapis_generator.dart:53:49)
   #3      generateAllLibraries (package:discoveryapis_generator/discoveryapis_generator.dart:64:28)
   #4      main (file:///home/tom/work/dart/dart-sdk/discovery_api_dart_client_generator/bin/generate.dart:112:40)
   #5      _startIsolate (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:237)
   #6      _startMainIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192)
   #7      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:130)**
```

Comment: What version of the discoveryapis_generator and Dart are you using? Maybe you should create an issue in the packages GitHub repo.

Comment: The dart version is 1.8.5. The generator version I don't know. I just cloned it yesterday.There's no command line option to get it.

Comment: I found another, possibly better supported but heavyweight generator  (https://github.com/google/apis-client-generator). It's giving me problems, too, but I'll create an issue on Github.

Comment: I think this https://github.com/dart-lang/discoveryapis_generator is the most recent package for this task and it doesn't have an `input` option only `input-dir`

Comment: Thanks. That's good to know I don't have to use apis-client-generator as it seems like overkill. The API version as included in the published discovery file at appspot.com is "v1". It's a really short document (36 lines). I fixed the input param and still get the same stack trace. Going over packages to create an issue...

Comment: Apparently the thing to do is actually fire up the development server and see what the real discovery document looks like. The one published on the appspot.com domain is apparently a stub.

Comment: I have just managed to create my first Dart client library using a Google cloud endpoints API discovery document. Very cool. I found using the "files" subcommand easier, as it didn't create new nested subdirectories, the structure of which are unfamiliar. Now to try and get the new library working from the Dart editor...